# How to change background of button on next click

Tags: android

Currently I have a list of `TextView`s whose background get changed when click for the first time. But I also want when user clicks on the second time its background should again change and vice versa.

With my existing code I am only able to change background for the first click, when I am clicking it again its background is not changing.

Here is my code:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {


        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.goalText1:
                if (count <= 2) {
                    goals.add(mGoal1.getText().toString());
                    mGoal1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    mGoal1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    count++;

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SelectGoal.this, "cant select more", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

            case R.id.goalText2:

                if (count <= 2) {
                    goals.add(mGoal2.getText().toString());
                    mGoal2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    mGoal2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    count++;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SelectGoal.this, "cant select more", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

            case R.id.goalText3:

                if (count <= 2) {
                    goals.add(mGoal3.getText().toString());
                    mGoal3.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    mGoal3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    count++;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SelectGoal.this, "cant select more", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

            case R.id.goalText4:

                if (count <= 2) {
                    goals.add(mGoal4.getText().toString());
                    mGoal4.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    mGoal4.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    count++;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SelectGoal.this, "cant select more", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.goalText5:

                if (count <= 2) {
                    goals.add(mGoal5.getText().toString());
                    mGoal5.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    mGoal5.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    count++;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SelectGoal.this, "cant select more", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.goalText6:

                if (count <= 2) {
                    goals.add(mGoal6.getText().toString());
                    mGoal6.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    mGoal6.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    count++;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SelectGoal.this, "cant select more", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.goalText7:

                if (count <= 2) {
                    goals.add(mGoal7.getText().toString());
                    mGoal7.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    mGoal7.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    count++;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SelectGoal.this, "cant select more", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;


            case R.id.btnGoal:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, fiteness_level_selection.class);


                try {
                    obj.put("SelectedGoal", goals);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                intent.putExtra("GoalJson", obj.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
                break;


        }
```

So can anybody suggest me any easy way to achieve it.

Comment: On click of textview, do you want to toggle between 2 provided colors or more?

Comment: So, you want the textview to change it's color alternatively? (between which colors?)

Comment: @Protino between white and transparent color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a boolean array in your activity.

```
//suppose you've 3 textviews within listview     
public boolean isTransparent[] = {false,false,false};
```

And then do this in your onClick method.

```
public void onOnclick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()) {
        //foreach textview do this
        case R.id.textView1 : 
            int color;
            if (isTransparent[0])
                color = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent);
            else
                color = getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
            isTransparent[0]=!isTransparent[0];
            textview1.setBackgroundColor(color);
            break;
       case R.id.textView2:
            // now check for isTransparent[1]
            and so on ...
            ...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As What I am understand is you want Change background for that you have take `bool` variable and in `Button` click you have to check the `bool` value.

```
Boolean click_firsttime = false;
```

Inside your `Button` click

use this way

```
If(click_firsttime == false){
//perform task 

// and set bool value to true
click_firsttime  = true;
}else{

// perform task and set bool value

click_firsttime  = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a boolean :

```
 private boolean foo = true;
```

Then change your code like this :

```
public void onClick(View v) {


    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.goalText1:
            if (foo) {
                goals.add(mGoal1.getText().toString());
                mGoal1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                mGoal1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                count++;
                foo = false;
            } else {
                // set background to another color
                foo = true;
            }
            break;
```